# Why is this code searching for a substring so much slower in C++ than in C#?

Tags: c#, c++

I have two different .txt file that contains 1.000.000 digits of pi and the first 200 fibonacci numbers.

Here pi1000000 ---> https://dotnetfiddle.net/DbcWBQ

Here fibonacci200 ---> https://dotnetfiddle.net/8o9hnB

My purpose is to search for all fibonacci numbers one by one in the pi.

I wrote in two programming languages: c++ and c#.

There is huge execution time difference between them. I don't know the reason.

For the same process, c# completes it in 4seconds and the c++ completes it in 80seconds.

Why there is huge execution time difference betweem them.

This is my algorithm to searh for a small string in a bigger one.

c# code

```
    public static void search(string text, string pattern)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= text.Length - pattern.Length; i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            while (j < pattern.Length)
            {
                if (text[i + j] != pattern[j]) break;
                j++;
            }

            if (j == pattern.Length)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Pattern is found at index: " + i.ToString() + " and the value is: " + pattern.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string pi = File.ReadAllText("pi1000000.txt", Encoding.ASCII);
        string[] fibo = File.ReadAllLines("fibonacci200.txt", Encoding.ASCII);

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            search(pi, fibo[i]);
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);

    }
```

c++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void search(string text, string pattern)
{
int t_l = text.length();
int p_l = pattern.length();
int difference = t_l - p_l;

for (int i = 0; i <= difference; i++)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (j; j < p_l; j++)
    {
        if (text[i + j] != pattern[j]) break;
    }
    if (j == p_l)
    {
        //cout << i << endl;
    }   
}
}

int main()
{
ifstream infile1;
string pi;
infile1.open("pi1000000.txt");
infile1 >> pi;
infile1.close();

short int i = 0;
string fibo[200];
string a;
ifstream infile2;
infile2.open("fibonacci200.txt");
while (getline(infile2, a))
{
        fibo[i] += a;
        i++;
}
infile2.close();

clock_t begin = clock();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    search(pi, fibo[i]);
}

clock_t end = clock();
double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

cout << elapsed_secs << endl; 

string x;
cin >> x;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you compile the C++ code with optimizations turned on? Also you only gave us the C# code, so its hard to say why the C++ code would be slower.

Comment: A good start would be to not copy the strings 200 times.

Comment: Please provide complete code. Why shave off includes?

Comment: If you pass the strings by reference does that change anything?

Comment: Part 5 of the infamous [Chinese dictionary contest](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ricom/2005/05/10/performance-quiz-6-chineseenglish-dictionary-reader/).  Link is broken to protect the guilty :)  But good hints on how to profile this code and find out how to make it better.

Comment: You are comparing badly written C++ with well written (I assume) C#.

Comment: I'm not sure, but could you trying `void search(string& text, string& pattern)`?

Comment: @HansPassant https://web.archive.org/web/20060814040954/http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/18/419130.aspx they're all guilty

Comment: @Nightingale Can you past `pi1000000.txt` and `fibonacci200.txt` at somewhere such as Github? I'm really very curious and want to try it :)

Comment: I added pi100000  and fibonacci200 files

Comment: @Nightingale It is a typro in pi1000000.txt? Guess it should be `3.1415...` other than `3,1415...`?

Comment: @Yuanhui [Some places use a dot decimal separator and others use a comma.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Arabic_numerals)

Comment: @Yuanhui Doesn't matter when it's treated as a string.

Comment: @Blastfurnace and molbdnilo, OK, and I got my test results of the different version. It is 6075.86us and almost 0us with reference version, other than 80s,  Nightingale, hope I have mistakes at somewhere ......

Answer (score 4):

In your C++ code you are appending all 1.000.000 digits of pi to the string `pi`, then you proceed to pass that huge huge string by value to `search` 200 times, that's at least 200 copies of that same huge string, with huge memory allocations and deletion.

Instead, pass it as reference:

```
void search(const string& text, const string& pattern)
```

And then check how the code snippets fare.

Even though you're doing the same in C# this isn't an issue because you're already passing a reference to the actual string because of how C# works.

---

I just tested the code myself with the new reference passing and tried release and debug x64 on MSVC, release optimizes out the whole loop because it's useless ( so not even testable ), debug finishes in 1 second.

Answer (score -2):

C++ code compiles down to machine instructions which is just in time(JIT) compilation but c# code compiles down to Comman Language Runtime (CLR) which is .NET framework from Microsoft provide good memory management and thread management.

Comment: The C++ code was inefficient because it did deep copies of the strings instead of passing them by reference (which is what the c# code was already doing). Your answer does not explain why *in this case* the C++ code was 20x slower than C# it just provides background information on how compiled code differs from JITed code.